# Closed / сallback not working when pressing inline button

Tags: python, aiogram

### Solution:

**In my case, the solution was to revoke the bot token**

---

Problem description:
When developing a bot in Python using the framework **aiogram 3.0.0b8**, was found a problem with the processing of callback_data, **when the button inline is pressed nothing happens**, but when you enter the command /heroes in the telegram **displays only the initial text**. callback_data is designed to change the text (next page, previous page)

---

**bot.py (*default code*):**

```
import logging
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage

from config_reader import config
from handlers import common, heroes
from utils.commands import set_commands


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def setup_logger(level: logging) -> None:
    format = "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(level=level, format=format)
    

def register_handlers(dp: Dispatcher) -> None:
    dp.include_router(common.router)
    dp.include_router(heroes.router)
    
    
async def main() -> None:
    storage = MemoryStorage()
    bot = Bot(token=config.bot_token.get_secret_value(), parse_mode="HTML")
    dp = Dispatcher(storage=storage)
    
    await set_commands(bot=bot)
    
    register_handlers(dp=dp)
    
    try:
        await bot.delete_webhook(True)
        await dp.start_polling(bot)
    finally:
        await dp.storage.close()
        await bot.session.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        setup_logger(logging.INFO)
        asyncio.run(main())
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        logging.info("bot stopped by ctrl+c")
```

---

**handlers/heroes.py:**

```
import logging

from aiogram import Router
from aiogram.filters import Command, Text
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import InlineKeyboardBuilder


currentNOH = 0 # current numbers of hero
currentPage = None

router = Router()


@router.message(Command("heroes"))
async def cmd_heroes(message: Message) -> None:
    global currentNOH
    global currentPage
    
    # creating 10 inline buttons
    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()

    for i in range(10):
        builder.button(text=str(i + 1), callback_data=f"hero_{i + 1}")
        currentNOH += 1

    builder.button(text="<", callback_data="back")
    builder.button(text=">", callback_data="next")
    builder.adjust(5, 5, 2)
    
    currentPage = await message.answer("Choose a hero:", reply_markup=builder.as_markup())

    logging.info("/HEROES <>MESSAGE<>")
    

@router.callback_query(Text(["back", "next"]))
async def change_page(query: CallbackQuery) -> None:

    logging.info("CALLBACK") # not calling when inline button pressed
    
    global currentPage
    global currentNOH
    
    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    
    if query.data == "back":
        if currentNOH > 10:
            for _ in range(10):
                builder.button(text=str(currentNOH - 1), callback_data=f"hero_{currentNOH - 1}")
                currentNOH -= 1
    elif query.data == "next":
        if currentNOH + 10 < 124:
            for _ in range(10):
                builder.button(text=str(currentNOH + 1), callback_data=f"hero_{currentNOH + 1}")
                currentNOH += 1
    
    builder.button(text="<", callback_data="back")
    builder.button(text=">", callback_data="next")
    
    if currentNOH <= 5:
        builder.adjust(currentNOH, 2)
    elif currentNOH <= 10:
        builder.adjust(5, currentNOH - 5, 2)
        
    currentPage = await query.message.edit_text("Choose a hero:", reply_markup=builder.as_markup())
```

---

**Terminal:**

```
$ python bot.py 
2023-06-30 18:10:59,804 - INFO - aiogram.dispatcher - Start polling
2023-06-30 18:10:59,894 - INFO - aiogram.dispatcher - Run polling for bot @telegrambot id=1234567890- 'telegrambot'
2023-06-30 18:11:00,817 - INFO - root - /HEROES <>MESSAGE<>
2023-06-30 18:11:00,817 - INFO - aiogram.event - Update id=123456789 is handled. Duration 296 ms by bot id=1234567890
# <-- Pressed the inline button, but the callback is inactive
```